# Flask Form fields not refreshing and flash messages not working

Tags: python, flask, web, bootstrap-4, flask-wtforms

I've looked everywhere and the examples aren't working for me code below:

I'm facing 2 problems with my code I'd be happy with a simple fix for each and go into an the advanced problem I'mm trying to solve

**Problem 1:** When I submit the form when the page refreshes the form fields still contain the information and are not blank. *(Advanced problem)* I'd like it to lock the fields and show a success message under the form like the original bootstrap form functioned this is a startbootstrap template i'm using  the free portfolio I believe for the framework

**Problem 2:** I can not retrieve the successful flashed message I can only display the flashed message if an error occurs and the messages only display when I go to validate the form the success message DOES NOT  display no matter what  even after  the form validates, *(advanced)* I'd like error messages to appear when the focus leaves the field like the original startbootstrap form

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, request, abort
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from forms import ContactForm
from datetime import date

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SomethingSecret'
Bootstrap(app)

current_year = date.today().year

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home_page():
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(u'Successfully sent your message')
        return redirect(url_for('home_page', form=form))

    return render_template('index.html', year=current_year, form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Online Portfolio</title>
        <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/favicon.ico')}}" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body id="page-top">
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">I Will Develop Your Dreams Online</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
{% with messages=get_flashed_messages() %}
 {% for category, message in messages %}
  <div class='alert text-center alert-dismissible fade show m-auto'>
    {{ message }}
   </div>
 {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% block body %}
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" data-sb-form-api-token="API_TOKEN">
                            <!-- Name input-->
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                {{ form.name(class_='form-control test', type='text', placeholder='Enter your name...') }}
                                {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                                    {% if messages %}
                                         <div>
                                        {% for message in messages %}
                                            {{ message }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endwith %}
                                <label for="name">Full name</label>
                            </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I guess the form did not validate. The program gives no warning or other feedback in such case.

Comment: i've used a print statement in the IF submit on validating and it prints when it validates the form